# jQuery function works in console but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ready

The code below creates a search field and then attaches a focus event to it so the preset value disappears when users click in the input field.  The .focus line works in the console but not in the code.  How can I get it to work in the code?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery('#site-nav').append("<div class='nav' style='width: 130px; margin-top: 15px;'><form     id='site-search' method='get' action='/search'><input id='search' name='search' class='textfield' tabindex='1' type='text' style='border-radius: 10px; height: 30px;' value='SEARCH'></form></div>")
});
jQuery("#search").focus(function(){$(this).val("");});
</script>
```

By the way, I have to spell out 'jQuery' because our app is configured that way to avoid conflicts
Thanks. Blessings

Comment: What's your reasoning behind using `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})` instead of the more common `$(function (){ ... })`?

Comment: @Malk [Uh, no you're wrong on that point](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @Craig: You only have to spell out `jQuery` outside of the `.ready()` callback. The issue in your code would probably be clearer to you if the indentation was consistent.

Comment: @amphetamachine - just ignorance...I don't use jQuery very often and I just copied it from notes

Comment: @cookie monster - good point.  My indentation changed trying to post the question though because it kept saying there was an error in my indentation.  Everyone else seems to figure those kinds of things out an I have a tough time with everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the line inside the `ready` method:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery('#site-nav').append("<div class='nav' style='width: 130px; margin-top: 15px;'><form     id='site-search' method='get' action='/search'><input id='search' name='search' class='textfield' tabindex='1' type='text' style='border-radius: 10px; height: 30px;' value='SEARCH'></form></div>");
    jQuery("#search").focus(function(){$(this).val("");});
});
```

Edit:

Keep in mind that the anonymous function in [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) always get triggered if the field gets the focus. So it will always be empty after this action